# Upgrading a Tenda router from H1_V3.2.5e-Feb 26 2009

Tags: router, upgrade, firmware

I have a Tenda router, and its current firmware is H1_V3.2.5e-Feb 26 2009. Which version should I upgrade to? Their site warns that selecting the wrong version can damage the router, and even upgrading through WiFi can damage it.

I don't even know what model my router is, only that the firmware is H1_V3.2.5e-Feb 26 2009.

Screenshot:

[image]

**Edit:**

This is a link that lists all the current firmware releases across many types of products supported by Tenda - http://tenda.cn/tendacn/DownLoads/search.aspx?catid=11. My firmware is mentioned there. But Tenda's website is not very intuitive, and they don't tell you which version to upgrade to.

**Edit 2:**

I found the model written on the router itself (I couldn't find it anywhere in the web interface) - the model is "W311R+".

Comment: It appears the UI is indicating the current installed firmware is `H1_V3.2.5e-Feb 26 2009` but what is the last revision released?  Why do you want to even update the firmware?  Yes;  You shouldn't upgrade the firmware over a wireless connection use a LAN connection.

Comment: @Ramhound I want to upgrade the router because my Internet connection is erratic, my ISP told me the router is flooding the WLAN, and some of the newer versions mention that they've fixed a WLAN flooding bug. Is that a good enough reason to want to upgrade?

Comment: As for "but what is the last revision released", I don't know which is the last revision, and that's what I'm hoping to learn by posting this question. I hope I've cleared up any misunderstandings.

Comment: Why didn't you ask your ISP for a download location of the firmware you wanted to use? I was able to find the current firmware offered by Trenda for that router without a problem. Of course what I actually I found was the download page for the `H1_V3.2.5e-Feb 26 2009` firmware ( which you are already using ) and I extrapulated which router you had based off that.  But what you should download is pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Ramhound Great, can you tell me the name of the firmware which I should download, since it's already clear to you? A download link will be even better :)

Comment: You never confirmed the router model.

Comment: @Ramhound See my edit, it's W311R+, it was written on the router itself. Good thing I didn't go with the extrapolation, they list another model in the site. I had been to their site even before I asked the question, btw, I do my research, but their site simply didn't inspire much trust in their competence.

Comment: **Ralink or broadcom chipset?**

Comment: @Ramhound Where do I look for that? I found neither "Ralink" nor "Broadcom" written anywhere on the router. Only "Wireless-N Broadband router" is written.

Comment: If your ISP provided this router they would be able to answer that question.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, it seems it is Broadcom chips, according to this link - http://www.tenda.cn/tendacn/commany/show.aspx?articleid=621.

Answer (score -1):

You need to find out your correct router model before you do anything, or you might brick it by uploading incompatible firmware. You can find it either on the device (usually printed on the bottom), or by checking information within the web interface. The model number is often listed on a page called "Status" or similar.

You should connect to it via ethernet cable if you intend to do the upgrade, so you don't lose connection and brick it.